# MySql date range query not showing all records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, date-format

I am working on mysql query right now. I write a query from fetch data from march 2018 to march 2019. There are more than 5000 records for this year. I write a query with date range from march 2018 to march 2019 but its showing me only 150 records

**One more thing here. The date column in database is varchar. I know its not good but it was taken accidently during creation of database and I am not able to change this to date type because of lots of data in database**

Here is the query I created

```
SELECT  a.*,b.* 
FROM OrderCalculation a 
right join crm_order b on a.orderid = b.orderno 
WHERE str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
AND str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d')  <= str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Please make this query correct if you think something wrong in it

Thank you

Comment: If we talk about March, shouldn't you use str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-03-01') rather than str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01')?

Comment: You could set the log to record all queries and check the SQL that's really being run. On production only run this for a short time - it can slow down your server. Why have you hard-coded the month -  should it not be just the day that's hard coded? Also, you should **NOT** have a field called `date` - it's a reserved word in SQL!! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: I would also **SRONGLY** urge you to take the time and effort to change your date field's data type to `DATE` from `VARCHAR`!

Comment: I try to change it but due to lots of data in the table its show me in incorrect date value @Vérace

Comment: How much is "lots"?

Comment: @Vérace around 8000 records

Comment: That is tiny for a table. Choose a slack period - I can't see it taking more than 15 mins at most - maybe even 15s! :-)

Comment: I don't mind how much time it will take but what about the error I am getting Incorrect date value

Comment: It would be good if you showed us a few sample rows from the table.

Answer (score 0):

> The date column in database is varchar.

You should really fix that.  If the string *always* looks like yyyy-mm-dd, then it will happen to work as a date.  (And my code below will work.)  That is, the string version of a `DATE` or `DATETIME` is handled almost identically the same as the proper datatype.  One major difference is:  "2019-08-01" versus "2019-8-1"

Do not hide a column (`Date`) inside a function call (`str_to_date`)

```
WHERE str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
  AND str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

-->

```
WHERE b.Date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND b.Date  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Did you really want 365 days, plus today?  This disagrees with your statement of "from march 2018 to march 2019".  (Plus March is 03, not 08.)

Now, `INDEX(Date)` *may* help with the speed of the query.  I say only "may" because the index will be ignored if the year is most of the table; it would be faster to ignore the table and simply scan the data.  (And my version will be as slow as yours).

Please rearrange your query to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`.  My brain has trouble with `RIGHT JOIN`.